# error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tintMode' with config

Tags: android

`error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tintMode' with config ''.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tintMode' with config ''., sources=[/Users/cfl/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/51ada31ae6adc43e314d87fd4e36e464/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}`

I updated android studio, and change sdk version to 27.1.1. When I compile then project, found this error. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: I have changed all appcompat v7 to 27.1.1, but it does not work.

Comment: If you updated your appcompat to 27.1.1 that is the right step. You may need to do an invalidate caches/restart as well

Comment: I found another atrr named 'tintMode' existed in a library. I changed it, and solved.

Comment: Nice one for resolving the error yourself!